# How to keep index in pandas pivot table

Tags: pandas

Suppose I create a pandas pivot table:

```
  adults_per_hh= pd.pivot_table(data,index=["hh_id"],values=["adult"],aggfunc=np.sum)
  adults_per_hh.shape
  (1000,1)
```

I want to keep hh_id as a column in addition to adult. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) if use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), because first column is `index`:

```
print (data)
   adult  hh_id
0      4      1
1      5      1
2      6      3
3      1      2
4      2      2

print (pd.pivot_table(data,index=["hh_id"],values=["adult"],aggfunc=np.sum))
       adult
hh_id       
1          9
2          3
3          6

adults_per_hh= pd.pivot_table(data,index=["hh_id"],values=["adult"],aggfunc=np.sum)
                .reset_index()
print (adults_per_hh)
   hh_id  adult
0      1      9
1      2      3
2      3      6
```

Another solution is use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and aggregate [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
adults_per_hh = data.groupby("hh_id")["adult"].sum().reset_index()
print (adults_per_hh)
   hh_id  adult
0      1      9
1      2      3
2      3      6
```

**Timings**:

```
#random dataframe
np.random.seed(100)
N = 10000000
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(50, size=(N,2)), columns=['hh_id','adult'])
#[10000000 rows x 2 columns]
print (data)

In [60]: %timeit (pd.pivot_table(data,index=["hh_id"],values=["adult"],aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index())
1 loop, best of 3: 384 ms per loop

In [61]: %timeit (data.groupby("hh_id", as_index=False)["adult"].sum())
1 loop, best of 3: 381 ms per loop

In [62]: %timeit (data.groupby("hh_id")["adult"].sum().reset_index())
1 loop, best of 3: 355 ms per loop
```

Comment: I don't want 1000 columns. I want 2 columns, 1 column for the hh_id, and one column for the count of adults.

Comment: I add timing, it seems `groupby` with `sum` and reset_index is the fastest.